# How to create a index for an mysql TEXT column using rails 3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, indexing

How to create an index for MySQL column using `rails 3`?

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/column-indexes.html)

> When you index a BLOB or TEXT column, you must specify a prefix
> length for the index.

How can I achieve the same using Rails 3

Answer (score 14):

In the migration you could do:

```
add_index(:table_name, :column_name, :length => 10)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_index - for more details

Answer (score -4):

Why are you creating an index? Do you plan on having a where clause on this column? If so, I strongly recommend against it as it will cripple your application in the long run. Use a search engine instead such as

1. [sphinx via thinking sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) or
2. [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: What a useless comment. There are many instances where an index on a text column is completely justified. Example: URLs require text (length > 255) and they are often (equality-)selected for to find duplicates. DB indexes are plenty fast, search engine features such as stemming aren't needed and the complexity of adding another service makes your idea an anti-pattern.

Comment: This answer is generally wrong and also not answering the question.